# How to hold Gamepad FIFA 15

Tags: controllers, fifa-15

I have been playing FIFA series since Fifa98 and have been using Keyboard all the time to play. Now I feel I should add some flair to my gameplay with skills for which I think the best option is to use a gamepad. I have a Logitech F310 gamepad like the one shown below.

[image]

I am pretty much confused about how to hold this properly. Right now i use like below

- LB - Left Index Finger
- LT = Left Middle Finger
- RB - Right Index Finger
- RT - Right Middle Finger
- LS - Left Thumb
- RS - Right Thumb
- X,A,B,Y - I use tip of the right thumb

The problem is performing fake shots and fake crosses, which are quite easily done on the keyboard. I find it very hard switch the thumb(X + A) and (B + A). I would like to hear from FIFA experienced gamepad users on their gamepad holding techniques and the advantages.

Comment: why the downvote??

Comment: i usually use the tip of my right thumb for X and Y and the middle part of my thumb as it rests over A. Then it's easy to press X + A and a short swivel to press A + B.

Comment: I don't believe there can be a "right" answer to this question. For example, I have long skeleton fingers and how I hold a controller might not be best and/or comfortable for other people. I also press both RB and RT with my index finger when I need to, but I use my index and middle finger for LB and LT... Would this be best for you? Don't know. Is this an answer? For me it's the most comfortable way. For you? I guess, it depends.

Answer (score 2):

There is not really a good answer for this as it's all preference but as for you problem with your A+X/ B+A you can just use your thumb to press both at the same time.

I usually press A not with the tip but a bit further down my thumb(I don't know the word in English).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you permanently leave your right thumb on the RS analogue stick. You don't need to do that. That stick is only useful for a couple of actions. I usually have the right thumb hovering over the four colorful buttons, and just move it to the stick if I want to do one of the trick actions.

For combinations like <kbd>X</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> I also use the joint my thumb to press the green button, while I use the tip of the thumb for the other button.

Comment: I tried finding a video that shows the player's hands. I know those exist, but I didn't find any.